# Browser not loading HTML response after doing jquery.ajax POST to a servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am having trouble loading some html that is returned by a servlet after doing a jquery.ajax post of mutliple files.

I can upload the files (pictures) just fine. I have a servlet that does some processing of the photos and extracts some metadata from the pictures. After processing the photos I want to pass some of the extracted metadata on to a JSP to eventually be returned to the browser.

All of this works fine. I load up the request object with my data and I redirect it to my JSP. However... whenever the JSP responds to the browser, the page doesn't get loaded.

Using firebug I can see that the JSP properly generates the HTML the way I want it to, and the browser gets the html text in the response... it just doesn't load the page. The page stays where it was and I can simply view the HTML text in the response in Firebug.

Any ideas what might be the problem? Here is some of the relevant code...

Javascript function which uploads the files to the servlet...

```
function uploadPictures() {
    var input = document.getElementById('filesToUpload');
    var fileList = [];
    var files = new FormData();

    for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++) {       
        files.append("file", input.files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        type        :   "POST",
        url         :   "/uploadPhotos",
        data        :   files,
        dataType    :   "HTML",
        processData :   false,
        contentType :   false
    });
}
```

Servlet Code

```
@MultipartConfig
public class UploadPhotosServlet extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String url = "/uploadForm.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = 
            getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
        String basePath = getInitParameter("photosRoot");
        HashMap<String,String> files = new HashMap<String,String>();

        java.util.Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
        for (Part part : parts) {
            String filename = getFilename(part);
            InputStream fileContent = part.getInputStream();

            OutputStream outFile = new FileOutputStream(new File(basePath + "screen/" + filename));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            while((read = fileContent.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                outFile.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }

            fileContent.close();
            outFile.flush();
            outFile.close();

            File img = new File(basePath + "screen/" + filename);
            File thumb = new File(basePath + "screen/thumbnails/" + filename);

            try {
                Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(img);

                for(Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
                    if(directory.containsTag(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL)) {
                        Date date = directory.getDate(ExifSubIFDDirectory.TAG_DATETIME_ORIGINAL);
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        files.put(filename, sdf.format(date));
                        break;
                    } else if(directory.containsTag(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_DATETIME)) {
                        Date date = directory.getDate(ExifIFD0Directory.TAG_DATETIME);
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        files.put(filename, sdf.format(date));
                        break;
                    }
                }

                BufferedImage buffImg = ImageIO.read(img);
                BufferedImage buffThumb = Scalr.resize(buffImg, 150);

                ImageIO.write(buffThumb, "jpg", thumb);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        request.setAttribute("files", files);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    private static String getFilename(Part part) {
        for (String cd : part.getHeader("content-disposition").split(";")) {
            if (cd.trim().startsWith("filename")) {
                String filename = cd.substring(cd.indexOf('=') + 1).trim().replace("\"", "");
                return filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf('/') + 1).substring(filename.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1); // MSIE fix.
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

As I stated above, the JSP that the redirects to (`uploadForm.jsp`) is generated just fine. Firebug will show me the HTML code in the response from the call to the servlet... However, the browser stays on the page that the upload form is on.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The page isn't supposed to be loaded when you do ajax. that's kinda the point, no page reload. If you want a page reload, don't use ajax. Otherwise, the content returned from the request is accessible within the success callback.

Comment: When I search the web for how to upload multiple files to a server, I only ever get AJAX methods. I've tried using XmlHttpRequest object as well, but with the same result. How would you suggest doing it in a "non-ajax" sort of way?

Comment: create a form, such as `<form action="myactpage.jsp"></form>`, move your file inputs into it, and then trigger the form's submit event.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to say that my tunnel vision prevented me from considering a simple form. I guess I just wanted it to be way more complicated than it needed to be. I've fixed it. Thanks for the help. I'll be happy to accept your answer if you want to post it that way. If not, thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you really want is much simpler than what you're currently doing.

```
<form action="/uploadPhotos" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" multiple name="filesToUpload" />
    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

ajax is not going to reload the page for you, that's the whole purpose of using ajax. However, you can force a page to reload by using the `complete` setting of ajax as documented here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

`complete` callback of ajax is always called after the ajax response come back regardless of the outcome (success or failure)

To put it together, you would want to do something like:

```
$.ajax({
    type        :   "POST",
    url         :   "/uploadPhotos",
    data        :   files,
    dataType    :   "HTML",
    processData :   false,
    contentType :   false,
    complete: function () {
         location.reload(); //or other browser specific reload method
    }
});
```

if `complete` is not what you wanted, try to use `success` or `error` instead.

`success` will be called when the return HTML status code is 2xx or 3xx

`error` will be called when the return HTML status code is 4xx or 5xx

utilize it according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

`AJAX` method is not supposed to refresh the page. You can use `window.location` if you want to in the `success` function of the `ajax` request

```
$.ajax({
    type        :   "POST",
    url         :   "/uploadPhotos",
    data        :   files,
    dataType    :   "HTML",
    processData :   false,
    contentType :   false,
    success: function(){
        window.location = "uploadForm.jsp";
    }
});
```